# Adding multiple columns from character vector to data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How can I add the columns `a, b, c` contained in `new_cols` to `data.table df` with the value `NA`? Preferably a nice solution without a loop.

```
df <- data.table(iris)
new_cols <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

Answer (score 2):

The `data.table` syntax would be to assign (`:=`) the `NA` to the column names specified in the object 'new_cols'

```
library(data.table)
df[, (new_cols) := list(NA)]
```

-output

```
> head(df)
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  a  b  c
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa NA NA NA
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa NA NA NA
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa NA NA NA
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa NA NA NA
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa NA NA NA
6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa NA NA NA
```